# Mysql query not working?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am making a simple friends feature for my site and when people get a friend request I want it to show on there friends panel link so I tried this.

```
 $q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT id_to read FROM friend_requests WHERE id = ? && read == '0'");
 $q -> execute(array($details['id']));
 $request_count = $q -> rowCount();
 if ($request_count > 0) {
echo '<li><a href="/friends"><img src="/gameimages/friends.png" height="16" width="16" alt="" /><strong>Friends (' . $request_count . ')</strong></a></li>';
 }
 else {
echo $request_count;
echo '<li><a href="/friends"><img src="/gameimages/friends.png" height="16" width="16" alt="" />Friends </a></li>';
 }
```

Now on the friends page where requests are shown all requests get the column of read set to 1, and by default it is 0. If there are rows with 0 it shall be a new request and the query above should fire letting users know that they have new requests, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Read* is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and need to be escaped with backticks:

```
SELECT id_to, `read` FROM friend_requests WHERE id = ? AND `read` = '0';
```

Comment: Ah ok even when I did the above it still did not work, and I have always used && in my mysql statements, what is this reserved for, do you know, and thanks :)

Comment: Some words need to be reserved for the SQL to be properly interpreted.   SELECT select ... is rather ambiguous don't you think? Read documentation for further information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your query:

```
SELECT id_to read FROM friend_requests WHERE id = ? && read == '0'
```

should be

```
SELECT id_to, read FROM friend_requests WHERE id = ? and read = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

> && read == '0'

Did you mean

```
 AND read = 0
```

?